# Dropbox109 process asking to access firewall on Yosemite

Tags: macos, dropbox, firewall, virus

As the title says, I have a process called **Dropbox109** asking to access the internet. I have denied it. 
I have Dropbox installed since Mavericks, and its been working fine (uploads/downloads/sync). What's suspicious is I got this Dropbox109 internet access request for the first time in a year of having Dropbox installed, and I couldn't find any information online.

Does anyone have any idea if it is a malicious program/virus or a legit process?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it’s a legitimate, routine request from Dropbox used to check your OS X version. Due to formatting limitations, I’m unable to directly embed [**this tweet**](https://twitter.com/dropbox_support/status/543183783495995393) from the official Dropbox support account. See the screenshot below, and click the link to view the tweet.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much for this! It makes sense - I recently upgraded to Yosemite. I REALLY appreciate the help!

Comment: @rgamber no problem. Cheers!

Comment: Do we know what's the purpose of the process? Because @rgamber said that denying internet access, didn't seem to affect dropbox functionality.